# Xbox One signs me out everytime

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

My xbox one is up to date and I have it on open access so I can just sign into my account with a password. But when I turn on my Xbox One I'm signed out AND I have to enter my password? What's wrong with my Xbox One? I know this might be considered a duplicate but my Xbox is completely up to date.

Comment: Check the settings on your account. You may have set it to require sign-in with password every time.

Answer (score 3):

My account is password protected as well, but I have the require password option turned off for when I boot up the Xbox One. Check your settings and hopefully that will correct the issue.